# TypeError: (0 , _context_stateContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.useStateContext) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a useContext() for an eCommerce store where I can pass data around to every single component, and change product quantities but I am running into an error. My app was functioning perfectly fine until I imported context();

Here is the code....

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';

const Context = createContext();

export const StateContext = ({ children }) => {
    const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState();
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState();
    const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState();
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

    const incQty = () => {
        setQty((prevQty) => prevQty + 1);
    }
    const decQty = () => {
        setQty((prevQty) => {
            if (prevQty - 1 < 1) return 1;
            return prevQty - 1;
        })
    }

    return (
        <Context.Provider
            value={{
                showCart,
                cartItems,
                totalPrice,
                totalQuantities,
                qty,
                incQty,
                decQty
            }}
        >
            { children }
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(Context);
```

When I try to import my useStateContext() into the file below, it throws an error and the entire app crushes.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AiFillStar, AiOutlineMinus, AiOutlinePlus, AiOutlineStar } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { Product } from '../../components';
import { client, urlFor } from '../../lib/client';

import { useStateContext } from '../../context/stateContext';

const ProductDetails = ({ product, products }) => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
    const { image, name, details, price } = product;
    const { decQty, incQty, qty } = useStateContext();
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="product-detail-container">
            <div>
                <div className='image-container'>
                    <img className='product-detail-image' src={urlFor(image && image[index])} alt="product image" />
                </div>
                <div className="small-images-container">
                    {image?.map((item, i) => (
                        <img 
                            src={urlFor(item)}
                            className={i === index ? "small-image selected-image" : "small-image"}
                            onMouseEnter={()=> setIndex(i)}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="product-detail-desc">
                  <h1>{name}</h1>
                  <div className="reviews">
                      <div>
                          <AiFillStar />
                          <AiFillStar />
                          <AiFillStar />
                          <AiFillStar />
                          <AiOutlineStar />
                      </div>
                      <p>(20)</p>
                  </div>
                  <h4>Details: </h4>
                  <p>{details}</p>
                  <p className="price">${price}</p>
                  <div className="quantity">
                      <h3>Quantity:</h3>
                      <p className="quantity-desc">
                          <span className="minus" onClick={decQty}>
                              <AiOutlineMinus />
                          </span>
                          <span className="num">
                              {qty}
                          </span>
                          <span className="plus" onClick={incQty}>
                              <AiOutlinePlus />
                          </span>
                      </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="buttons">
                      <button type="button" className='add-to-cart' onClick="">
                          Add to Cart
                      </button>
                      <button type='button' className="buy-now" onClick="">
                          Buy Now
                      </button>
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div> 
        
          <div className="maylike-products-wrapper">
              <h2>You may also like</h2>
              <div className='marquee'>
                  <div className="maylike-products-container track">
                      {products.map((item) => (
                          <Product key={item._id} product={item} />
                      ))}
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductDetails;

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: {slug}}) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "product" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]`;
    const productsQuery = '*[_type == "product"]';

    const product = await client.fetch(query);
    const products = await client.fetch(productsQuery);

    console.log(product);
    return {
        props: { product, products}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are wrapping your _app.js with **`<StateContext> ....</StateContext>`**. For my case I did some renaming and works.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';

import { Layout } from '../components/Index';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { AppContextProvider } from '../context/StateContext';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <AppContextProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Toaster />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </AppContextProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

```css
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import {
  AiOutlineMinus,
  AiOutlinePlus,
  AiFillStar,
  AiOutlineStar
} from 'react-icons/ai';

import { client, urlFor } from '../../lib/client';
import { Product } from '../../components/Index';
import { useAppContext } from '../../context/StateContext';

const ProductDetails = ({ product, products }) => {
  const { image, name, details, price } = product;
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const { decQty, incQty, qty, onAdd, setShowCart } = useAppContext();

  const handleBuyNow = () => {
    onAdd(product, qty);

    setShowCart(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="product-detail-container">
        <div>
          <div className="image-container">
            <img
              src={urlFor(image && image[index])}
              className="product-detail-image"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="small-images-container">
            {image?.map((item, i) => (
              <img
                key={i}
                src={urlFor(item)}
                className={
                  i === index ? 'small-image selected-image' : 'small-image'
                }
                onMouseEnter={() => setIndex(i)}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="product-detail-desc">
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <div className="reviews">
            <div>
              <AiFillStar />
              <AiFillStar />
              <AiFillStar />
              <AiFillStar />
              <AiOutlineStar />
            </div>
            <p>(20)</p>
          </div>
          <h4>Details: </h4>
          <p>{details}</p>
          <p className="price">${price}</p>
          <div className="quantity">
            <h3>Quantity:</h3>
            <p className="quantity-desc">
              <span className="minus" onClick={decQty}>
                <AiOutlineMinus />
              </span>
              <span className="num">{qty}</span>
              <span className="plus" onClick={incQty}>
                <AiOutlinePlus />
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="buttons">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="add-to-cart"
              onClick={() => onAdd(product, qty)}
            >
              Add to Cart
            </button>
            <button type="button" className="buy-now" onClick={handleBuyNow}>
              Buy Now
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="maylike-products-wrapper">
        <h2>You may also like</h2>
        <div className="marquee">
          <div className="maylike-products-container track">
            {products.map((item) => (
              <Product key={item._id} product={item} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "product"] {
    slug {
      current
    }
  }
  `;

  const products = await client.fetch(query);

  const paths = products.map((product) => ({
    params: {
      slug: product.slug.current
    }
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking'
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { slug } }) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "product" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]`;
  const productsQuery = '*[_type == "product"]';

  const product = await client.fetch(query);
  const products = await client.fetch(productsQuery);

  console.log(product);

  return {
    props: { products, product }
  };
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

```html
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';

const AppContext = createContext(null);

export const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);
  const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState(0);
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const incQty = () => {
    setQty((prevQty) => prevQty + 1);
  };
  const decQty = () => {
    setQty((prevQty) => {
      if (prevQty - 1 < 1) return 1;
      return prevQty - 1;
    });
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        showCart,
        cartItems,
        totalPrice,
        totalQuantities,
        qty,
        incQty,
        decQty
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useAppContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(AppContext);
  if (!context) {
    console.error('Error deploying App Context');
  }
  return context;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Next.js make sure to add 'use client' in your components.